# Why is Access token from app registration encrypted when requesting openid scope?

Tags: azure, authentication, token, azure-app-registration

For a SPA/ mobile app I've set up a login using an app registration in Azure. The login works perfectly fine, but when I request the openid scope (which is also set in the app registration), I get an (I think) encrypted token, the access token starts with `PAQABAAIAAAA`. When I do not request this scope in the SPA/ mobile app, it will return me a normal jwt token which starts with `ey`. Is there any reason why this token is encrypted? Or is this a poor implementation on the [dependency](https://github.com/wi3land/ionic-appauth/tree/master) side which I'm using for this?

I've found no resource related to this, not on Azure's side, but also not on the dependencies side.

Comment: Could you confirm what type of account you are using to login? personal Microsoft accounts or work accounts?

Comment: @Sridevi I'm using work accounts, the encryption happens in 2 different tenants as well

Comment: Could you include more details like code you are using or any links you referred to set up authentication and getting token?

Comment: The depedency I use is basically a wrapper for multiple other depedencies which makes it easy to implement openid for SPA in the normal web browser but also on native apps with capacitor. My implementation is almost the same as the example over [here](https://github.com/wi3land/ionic-appauth/tree/master/demos/vue)